# Listbox is displaying class name instead of values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project where the user is supposed to input values to animal (Name, age, gender etc..) and the values entered by the user are  supposed to display on a list-box
The classes inherit from each other. Here is how the inheritance work:

> *Animal* class is the parent for all classes.
>
> *Mammal* class inherit from *Animal* class.
>
> *Dog* class inherit from *Mammal* class.
>
> *Cat* class inherit from *Mammal* class
>
> *Reptile* class inherit from *Animal* class
>
> *Snake* class inherit from *Reptile* class
>
> *Lizard* class inherit from *Reptile* class

The user is able to choose what animal to create. There is one listbox showing the type of animal (Mammal and Reptile) and there is a listbox next to it that that depending on the type of animal selected by the user, it displays its animals.

For exampel, if the user selects *Mammal* in the listbox, the listbox next to it displays *Dog* and *Cat*.

This is working perfectly and it's not the problem.

**The problem** is that when the user enters the animal values (Name and Age) after selecting the animal type in the listbox(for example *Mammal*, *Dog*) and clicks the add button, the  result listbox displays *Assign1_1.Mammal* when trying to add a Mammal animal and *Assign_1.Reptile* when trying to add a Reptile animal.

What I want it to do is to display the values the user entered (Name and Age) in the result listbox but instead it just says *Assign1.Mammal* or *Assign1.Reptile* depending on the selected animal.

Here is my MainForm code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assign_1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Dog m_dog = new Dog();
        private Cat m_cat = new Cat();
        private Snake m_snake = new Snake();
        private Lizard m_lizard = new Lizard();
        private AnimalManager animalmgr  = null;
        private Animal m_animal = new Animal();
        public MainForm()
        {

            //Visual Studio initializations
            InitializeComponent();

            //My initializations
            InitializeGUI();
            Gendercmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType));
            Categorylst.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categorytype));
            animalmgr = new AnimalManager();

        }

        private void InitializeGUI()
        {
            ReadInput();
        }

        private void ReadInput()
        {
            m_animal.Name = ReadName();
            m_animal.Age = ReadAge();
        }
        private int ReadAge()
        {
            int age = 0;

            int.TryParse(Agetxt.Text, out age);

            return age;
        }

        private string ReadName()
        {
            string name = "";
            name = Nametxt.Text;
            return name;
        }

        private void addMammal(Mammal values)
        {

            ReadInput();

            switch ((MammalType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
            {
                 case MammalType.Dog:
                    {

                        // Use a copy constructor to set a dog with common data
                        Dog m_dog = new Dog(values);
                        // If more data in GUI to fill in for this animal, do it here
                        //Then send it to the manager for adding to the list
                        animalmgr.add(m_dog);
                        break;
                   } 
                case MammalType.Cat:
                    {
                        Cat m_cat = new Cat();
                        animalmgr.add(m_cat);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        private void AddReptile(Reptile values)
        {
            ReadInput();

            switch ((ReptileType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case ReptileType.Snake:
                    {

                        // Use a copy constructor to set a snake with common data
                        Snake m_snake = new Snake(values);
                        // If more data in GUI to fill in for this animal, do it here
                        //Then send it to the manager for adding to the list
                        animalmgr.add(m_snake);
                        break;
                    }
                case ReptileType.Lizard:
                    {
                        Lizard m_lizard = new Lizard();
                        animalmgr.add(m_lizard);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        //When user clicks "Add to list"
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadInput();

            switch ((Categorytype)Categorylst.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case Categorytype.Mammal:
                    {
                        Mammal mammal = new Mammal(m_animal);
                        addMammal(mammal);
                        break;
                    }
                case Categorytype.Reptile:
                    {
                        Reptile m_reptile = new Reptile(m_animal);
                        AddReptile(m_reptile);
                        break;
                    }


            }
            UpdateResults();
        }
        private void UpdateResults()
        {

            Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.ElementCount; index++)
            {
                Animal animal = animalmgr.GetElementAtPosition(index);

                Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Here is my Animal manager class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign_1
{
    class AnimalManager
    {
        private List<Animal> m_animal;
        private List<Mammal> m_mammal;
        public AnimalManager()
        {
            //In this list objects off diff animals of all species are saved
            m_animal = new List<Animal>();
            m_mammal = new List<Mammal>();
        }


        public void add(Animal ObjIn)
        {
            m_animal.Add(ObjIn);
        }

        public bool IsIndexValid(int index)
        {
            return ((index >= 0) && (index < m_animal.Count));
        }

        public Animal GetElementAtPosition(int index)
        {
            //We choose to return a copy, why do I need type casting when copying?
        if (IsIndexValid(index))
            {
                if (m_animal[index] is Mammal)
                    return new Mammal((Mammal)m_animal[index]);
                if (m_animal[index] is Reptile)
                    return new Reptile((Reptile)m_animal[index]);
                return null;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public int ElementCount
        {
            get { return m_animal.Count; }
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my mammal class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign_1
{
    class Mammal : Animal
    {
        private MammalType theMammal;
        private int teeth;


        public Mammal() : base()
             {

             }
        public Mammal(Animal other)
        {
            this.Name = other.Name;
            this.Age = other.Age;
            this.Gender = other.Gender;
            this.Id = other.Id;

        }

        public Mammal (MammalType type)
        {
            theMammal = type; 
        }

#region Props
        public MammalType TheMammal
        {
            get { return theMammal; }
            set { theMammal = value; }
        }


        public int Teeth
        {
            get { return teeth; }
            set { teeth = value; }
         }
#endregion


    }
}
```

Here is my Dog class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign_1
{
    class Dog : Mammal
    {


        public Dog()
        {

        }
      public Dog(Mammal other)
    {
      this.Name = other.Name;
      this.Age = other.Age;
      this.Teeth = other.Teeth;
    }


    }
}
```

**EDIT**
To do this simpler, I'm only showing child class *Mammal* and *Dog*. If I'm able to figure out how to create a *Dog*, I can probably fix the others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add an override of the `ToString()` method in your classes.
The override returns the value that you choose to display in your ListBoxes.

The ListBox, when is ready to display the items, use the `ToString` method of the class instance that is added to its items collection. If there is no ToString() then the base class `Object.ToString()` is used and that method returns just the class name

For example you could change the Dog class with

```
class Dog : Mammal
{
    public Dog()
    {
    }
    public Dog(Mammal other)
    {
       this.Name = other.Name;
       this.Age = other.Age;
       this.Teeth = other.Teeth;
    } 
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
               this.Name, this.Age, this.Teeth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to override the `ToString()`-method. Note the `override` keyword in the signature.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    //You can put anything here and it will be returned by the ToString()-method.
    return this.Name + ", " + this.Age;
}
```

Put this code in your `Dog`-class. It will make `dog.ToString()` return `Name, Age`.

Also, you can actually put this override in your base class, Animal, and it will be carried over to all the subclasses. As long as they don't override `ToString()` themselves they will also return `Name, Age`.

Comment: @Simon No worries :) Just as an extra note, you can actually put this override in your base class, Animal, and it will be carried over to all the subclasses. As long as they don't override ToString themselves they will also return `Name, Age`.

Comment: Kan du hjälpa mig med den här frågan?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283543/listbox-cannot-display-child-class-variable)