# Listbox cannot display child class variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project where the user is inputing values to animal (Name, age, gender etc..) and the values entered by the user are displayed on a list-box
The classes inherit from each other. Here is how the inheritance work:

> *Animal* class is the parent for all classes.
>
> *Mammal* class inherit from *Animal* class.
>
> *Dog* class inherit from *Mammal* class.
>
> *Cat* class inherit from *Mammal* class
>
> *Reptile* class inherit from *Animal* class
>
> *Snake* class inherit from *Reptile* class
>
> *Lizard* class inherit from *Reptile* class

The variables for Animal is *id*, *name*, *age*, *gender*.

The variable for Mammal is *teeth*

The variable for Dog is *barkLevel*

The user is able to choose what animal to create. There is one listbox showing the type of animal (Mammal and Reptile) and there is a listbox next to it that depending on the type of animal selected by the user, it displays its animals.

For exampel, if the user selects *Mammal* in the listbox, the listbox next to it displays *Dog* and *Cat*.

This is working perfectly and it's not the problem.

**The problem:**

The input values are being displayed on the result list, but not the child class variables. The result listbox **is** displaying *Id*, *Name*, *Age*, *Gender* but **not** *teeth* or *barkLevel*. There are no error messages or anything. It just doesn't display the child class variables.

Here is my MainForm:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Assign_1
    {
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {
            private Dog m_dog = new Dog();
            private Cat m_cat = new Cat();
            private Snake m_snake = new Snake();
            private Lizard m_lizard = new Lizard();
            private AnimalManager animalmgr  = null;
            private Animal m_animal = new Animal();
            private Mammal m_mammal = new Mammal();
            public MainForm()
            {

                //Visual Studio initializations
                InitializeComponent();

                //My initializations
                InitializeGUI();
                Gendercmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType));
                Categorylst.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categorytype));
                animalmgr = new AnimalManager();

            }

            private void InitializeGUI()
            {
                ReadInput();
            }

            private void ReadInput()
            {
                m_animal.Name = ReadName();
                m_animal.Age = ReadAge();
                m_mammal.Teeth = ReadTeeth();
                m_dog.BarkLevel = ReadBarklevel();

                m_animal.Gender = this.Gendercmb.GetItemText(this.Gendercmb.SelectedItem);


            }
            private int ReadAge()
            {
                int age = 0;

                int.TryParse(Agetxt.Text, out age);

                return age;
            }
            private int ReadBarklevel()
            {
                int bark = 0;

                int.TryParse(barktxt.Text, out bark);

                return bark;

            }
            private int ReadTeeth()
            {
                int teeth = 0;

                int.TryParse(teethtxt.Text, out teeth);

                return teeth;
            }

            private string ReadName()
            {
                string name = "";
                name = Nametxt.Text;
                return name;
            }

            private void addMammal(Mammal values)
            {

                ReadInput();

                switch ((MammalType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
                {
                     case MammalType.Dog:
                        {

                            // Use a copy constructor to set a dog with common data
                            Dog m_dog = new Dog(values);
                            // If more data in GUI to fill in for this animal, do it here
                            //Then send it to the manager for adding to the list
                            animalmgr.add(m_dog);
                            break;
                       } 
                    case MammalType.Cat:
                        {
                            Cat m_cat = new Cat(values);
                            animalmgr.add(m_cat);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            private void AddReptile(Reptile values)
            {
                ReadInput();

                switch ((ReptileType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case ReptileType.Snake:
                        {

                            // Use a copy constructor to set a snake with common data
                            Snake m_snake = new Snake(values);
                            // If more data in GUI to fill in for this animal, do it here
                            //Then send it to the manager for adding to the list
                            animalmgr.add(m_snake);
                            break;
                        }
                    case ReptileType.Lizard:
                        {
                            Lizard m_lizard = new Lizard();
                            animalmgr.add(m_lizard);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            //When user clicks "Add to list"
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ReadInput();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(m_dog.BarkLevel.ToString());

                switch ((Categorytype)Categorylst.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case Categorytype.Mammal:
                        {
                            Mammal mammal = new Mammal(m_animal);
                            addMammal(mammal);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Categorytype.Reptile:
                        {
                            Reptile m_reptile = new Reptile(m_animal);
                            AddReptile(m_reptile);
                            break;
                        }


                }
                UpdateResults();
            }
            private void UpdateResults()
            {

                Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
                //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
                //ToString method for info - send to listbox
                for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.ElementCount; index++)
                {
                    Animal animal = animalmgr.GetElementAtPosition(index);
 toString method.
                    Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString()); // <--- Here is the problem
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my Animal manager class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign_1
{
    class AnimalManager
    {
     //   private List<Animal> m_animalList;
        private List<Animal> m_animal;
        private List<Mammal> m_mammal;
        public AnimalManager()
        {
            //In this list objects off diff animals of all species are saved
            //   m_animalList = new List<Animal>();
            m_animal = new List<Animal>();
            m_mammal = new List<Mammal>();
        }


        public void add(Animal ObjIn)
        {
            m_animal.Add(ObjIn);
        }

        public bool IsIndexValid(int index)
        {
            return ((index >= 0) && (index < m_animal.Count));
        }

        public Animal GetElementAtPosition(int index)
        {
            //We choose to return a copy
        if (IsIndexValid(index))
            {
                if (m_animal[index] is Mammal)
                    return new Mammal((Mammal)m_animal[index]);
                if (m_animal[index] is Reptile)
                    return new Reptile((Reptile)m_animal[index]);
                return null;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public int ElementCount
        {
            get { return m_animal.Count; }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I know now that the problem is `Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());` Somehow I need to include the mammal and dog object (depending on the selected animal) but I don't know how.

Comment: could you post less info? try only relevant info

Comment: Your results are only asking for the animal: `Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());`  If you have to constantly check what object you have, you are doing inheritance wrong.  Just add the object as-is to the ListBox and let the ToString do its work.

Comment: @LarsTech Could you give an example, please.

Comment: @LarsTech What do you mean with object as-is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell you're never actually returning your sub classes. Assuming you've got all your cats, dogs, snakes and lizards in `m_animal`, when you run them through the base class constructors you are actually losing the properties of the sub classes. Try returning the objects directly:

```
public Animal GetElementAtPosition(int index)
{
    if (IsIndexValid(index))
        return m_animal[index];
    else
        return null;
}
```

Provided you have `ToString()` overridden in all your classes you should be getting the result you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks. I think the only problem is that `m_animal` doesn't really include the sub classes(cats, dogs, snakes and lizards), and I'm not really sure how to add them to the `m_animal` list. As you can see in my Animal manager class the sub classes are not included in the `m_animal` list

Comment: I figured out the problem. Thank you very much for everything.