# ListBox data to Textbox [ ASPX.VB]

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, webapplicationstresstool

I'm in a project where I pass the information in two Textbox to a ListBox. But I would like to know if it is possible for me to double click on ListBox items and return to the TextBox where it came from to make edition. In Visual Basic - WebApplication

Comment: Please ask your question only in english.

Comment: @live2 ok. It’s now in English. Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code example how you merge the two textboxes?

Comment: You can save your information separately in a class and then use it in the listbox or you can split your text later. For the class example you can use `public override string ToString()` Check this answer [Listbox is displaying class name instead of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268419/listbox-is-displaying-class-name-instead-of-values)

Comment: I have a image here but I can upload, I don’t have my code here  but I now when I use one button the text of Textbox 1 and 2 go to the ListBox

Comment: Thank u live2. But I didn’t understand your point of view 